# Can a pregnant woman travel on a cruise ship without restriction?

Tags: health, regulations, cruising, pregnancy

Are there any laws or regulations that forbid pregnant women from participating on a cruise? Or does this vary from organization to organization. If so, are there any common rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with airlines, cruise lines each have their own regulations. It appears to be fairly common that pregnancies later than 24 weeks (=6 months, i.e. 3rd trimester) are disallowed, or at least discouraged. This is earlier than for travelling by plane.

[allthingscruise.com](http://allthingscruise.com/cruise-research/niche-cruises/family-cruising/pregnancy-policies-by-cruise-line/) has an extensive list of regulations, though it may be advisable to contact the cruise line directly.